# How to utilize 2 criteria for a whatif formula/array formula

Tags: google-sheets

I need to create a count of data that meets two criteria. Column one consist of dates. For this one, the input to count is today, or TODAY(). The dates will be entered in B2:B100

The second column is Status with desired input to count is "To Do".  The status will be entered in D2:D100.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the **[COUNTIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550)** formula to do that, like so:

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B100, TODAY(), D2:D100, "To Do")
```

Comment: This would be the better way to do it. Completely forgot this had a multiple argument type.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do this is to do an evaluation in a new column, then check the output value with your countif statement.

In one column have it determine whether or not both criteria are met:

```
=IF(AND(B2 = SOMETHING, D2 = SOMETHING_ELSE),"TRUE","FALSE")
```

What this does is says that if B2 is equal to SOMETHING and D2 is equal to SOMETHING_ELSE, return the string "TRUE", if both conditions are not met than return the string "FALSE".

So if we put the formula above in column G the countif would look something like:

```
=countif(G:G,"TRUE")
```

Anything which returned a string "TRUE" will be counted, and the ones which failed the AND criteria and returned the string "FALSE" are not counted.